# How to fix ' Support for the experimental syntax 'exportDefaultFrom' isn't currently enabled' in node

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules, babel-loader

I have a full stack javascript application running on React, Node, express. 
The problem is `export` without `default` is not working in node, However, It is working fine in react.
Both my node and react share the same babel configs and packages.

I've already tried adding the `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from` package in my `babel.config.js` but after doing so, it generates another error

> Unexpected token (25:16) export getMember;

I even tried removing the semicolumn

Here's my `babel.config.js`

```
    module.exports = {
      "presets": ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
          {
            "loose": true
          }
        ]
      ]

};
```

Here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "dpapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server.js --ignore dist/",
    "dev": "webpack -wd"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.11",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dropbox": "^4.0.17",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.7",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.5.0",
    "query-string": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0"
  }
}
```

Here's my code where the error is occuring

```
import dbx from '../dropbox';

const getMember = async (req, res, next) => {

    try{


        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Account created"
        });



    } catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).json({
            error: error
        });
    }

}

export getMember;
```

Comment: Can be fixed by using this babel plugin

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-syntax-export-default-from.html

Answer (score 6):

You should use `export default getMember` or `export { getMember }` or `export const getMember = async...`.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: only `export default getMember` is working, but I don't want this to be a default export

Comment: You cannot use export the way you have used it. If you don't want it to be a default then you have to use the other way of exporting it with named exports `export { getMember }` and then when importing you will have to use the `import { getMember } from './path/to/file'` syntax.

Comment: Yes, I tried it this way. but this didn't work either

Comment: What error is it giving you? Does it give the same error?

Comment: I think maybe the problem is that you need to transpile the nodejs code, since `export` only works with es6 and node does not support es modules by default. Alternatively you can try this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm.

Comment: Does this answer the question?